# How to validate for Uniqueness of more than one fields from two related tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am having trouble in validating uniqueness of multiple fields. I have the following models:

```
class ClassSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course_assignment_section
end
class CourseAssignmentSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course_assignment
  has_many :class_schedules
end
class CourseAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
  has_many :course_assignment_sections, :dependent => :destroy
end
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_assignments
end
```

When creating class_schedule, i want to check uniqueness validation of two fields, period_id and instructor_id, period_id is a field found in class_schedules table, and instructor_id is a field that can be found through: `course_assignment_section.course_assignment.instructor`  i have course_assignment_section_id field in class_schedules table). How can i validate for uniqueness of two fields from different tables. I would appreciate quick help. thanks.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to validate uniqueness of the period_id field with scope instructor_id, but instructor_id is not a field found in class_schedules table, i have a field called course_assignment_section_id in class_schedules table so i can access the instructor_id through this field using the relationship between the models as stated above.